# Add and Delete Row in a HTML TABLE using javascript only

Tags: javascript, html

My task is to create a HTML table with add and delete button. Delete button should be in each row to delete the entire row and automate the indexing. I am facing issues in indexing and after row is added. How to put delete button?

```js
function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}
function addRow() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var classVariable = document.getElementById("class").value;
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]
    var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = "5";
    cell2.innerHTML = name;
    cell3.innerHTML = classVariable;
    
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1px">
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Class</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Jhone</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" id="btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    Class : <input type="number" name="class" id="class">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow()">
```

Comment: When you create a snippet, you have better chance of getting good answer!

Comment: You will also often find errors yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this solution, maybe you can use the code. It also prevents users from entering the same values again.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var buttons = table.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var newbutton = document.getElementById("new");
    var namefield = document.getElementById("name");
    var classfield = document.getElementById("class");

    function createIndex(){
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].dataset.index = i;
            if(i > 0){
                rows[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML = i;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].dataset.index = i+1;
        }
    }

    function createCell(row,i,value){
        let cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.innerHTML = value;
    }

    function addRow(){
        if(namefield.value !== '' && classfield.value !== ''){
            let row = table.insertRow(-1);
            createCell(row,0,'');
            createCell(row,1,namefield.value);
            createCell(row,2,classfield.value);
            createCell(row,3,'<button class="delete">Delete</button>');
            createIndex();
            namefield.value = '';
            classfield.value = '';
        }
        else{
            alert('Please enter data!');
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(index){
        let row = document.querySelector('[data-index="'+index+'"]');
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        createIndex();
    }

    var clickEvent = document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
        if(event.target.classList.contains('delete')){
            deleteRow(event.target.getAttribute('data-index'));
        }
        if(event.target.id === 'new'){
            addRow();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    createIndex();

});
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1px">
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Jhone</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>James</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        Class : <input type="number" name="class" id="class">
        <button id="new">+ ADD</button>
```

Comment: How can i add edit feature to it??

Answer (score 0):

I made reindex function, which loops through all columns with index, and sets them to iterator value +1. This function is called at the end of delete or add row. This way you keep your indexes right.

To add delete button I created new button element and added onclick using setAttribute.

```js
function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
    reindex();
}

function reindex() {
  const ids = document.querySelectorAll("tr > td:nth-child(1)");
  ids.forEach( (e, i) => { e.innerText=(i+1) } );
}

function addRow() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var classVariable = document.getElementById("class").value;
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    
    // delete button
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Delete";
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteRow(this)");
    
    var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = "5";
    cell2.innerHTML = name;
    cell3.innerHTML = classVariable;
    cell4.appendChild( button );
    
     reindex();
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1px">
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Class</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Jhone</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" id="btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    Class : <input type="number" name="class" id="class">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow()">
```

Comment: how to add edit feature to this??